# Создание результирующей колонки в Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Имеется набор данных вида:

```
id  season  division round localTeam visitorTeam localGoals visitorGoals date timestamp
0   1   1970-71 1   1   Athletic Club   Barcelona   1   1   12/09/1970  21942000
1   2   1970-71 1   1   Las Palmas  Atletico de Madrid  1   1   12/09/1970  21942000
2   3   1970-71 1   1   Real Madrid Valencia    2   0   12/09/1970  21942000
3   4   1970-71 1   1   Celta de Vigo   Sporting de Gijon   2   0   13/09/1970  22028400
4   5   1970-71 1   1   Elche   Granada 1   1   13/09/1970  22028400
```

Как создать дополнительную колонку, в которой будет отображаться название победившей в матче команды ? То есть если счет "команды 1" больше счета "команды 2", в результирующей колонке отобразится, что победила "команда 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
football = pd.DataFrame({'visitorGoals':[1,1,2,1], 'localGoals':[1,0,0,1], \
'localTeam':['Athletic Club','Las Palmas','Real Madrid','Celta de Vigo'],\
'visitorTeam':['Barcelona','Atletico de Madrid','Valencia','Sporting de Gijon']
})

football['winner_team'] = np.where(football['visitorGoals']>football['localGoals'], football['visitorTeam'],\
np.where(football['visitorGoals']<football['localGoals'], football['localTeam'], 'draw'))
```

Comment: @Andrew, дадите какой-нибудь фидбэк? мой ответ был вам полезен?

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Извините за задержку